# opening a Popup in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have hyperlink column in grid and clicking the link i want to open a popup. Below is my code.

```
cols.Bound(o => o.PO_NO)
    .ClientTemplate(
        Html.ActionLink("<#=PO_NO#>", 
                        "SurPODtls", 
                        new { controller = "Home", PO_NO = "<#=PO_NO#>" }, 
                        new { target= "_self" }).ToString())
    .Title("PO No").Width(30).Filterable(false);
```

In SurPODtls action method iam returning the partial view of SurPODtls, which contains the telrik window in which iam again calling the partial view to load the controls and data. And same time i have to retain the grid.

But this not works for me. Please provide solution, if anyone have idea

Comment: Have you seen http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customcolumncommand

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Custom Column Command` here is the link http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customcolumncommand